# Rebuild index with zero downtime

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Currently working on something and needed some help.  I will have an elastic index populated from a sql database.  There will be an initial full reindex from the sql database then there will be nightly job which will update / delete / insert updates.

In the event of a major failure I may need to do full reindex. Ideally i want zero downtime.  I did find some articles about creating aliases etc however this sees to be more updates to field mappings.  My situation is a full reindex of the data from my source db.  Can i just get that data push the docs to elastic and elastic will just update the existing index as ids will be same?  Or do i need to do something else?

Regards

Ismail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For zero downtime you can create a new index, populate it from your database, and use the alias to switch from the old index to the new one. Steps:

1. Call your main index something like main_index_1 (or whatever you like)
2. Create an alias for that index called main_index

   `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/main_index_1/_alias/main_index?pretty`
3. Set up your application to point to this alias
4. Create a new index called main_index_2 and index it from your database
5. Switch the alias to point to the new index

   `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d
   {
       "actions": [
           { "remove": { "index": "main_index_1", "alias": "main_index" }},
           { "add":    { "index": "main_index_2", "alias": "main_index" }}
       ]
   }`

Comment: Cool, however just pushing up data should just update existing data and still keep the index up so 0 downtime as well?

Comment: Yes, in theory, but you were talking about major failure. What would fail in this case?

Comment: Sorry may bad.  The data updates i get from db has to have been extracted and pushed up within a time frame. After that time frame that data is over written with new data.  If during that time the data extraction fails then i need to rebuild full index. However during that rebuild i want the index still to be up even though it potentially has stale data.

Comment: If seeing stale data is ok, you can go and update the existing index, this won't cause any downtime either.

Comment: I found that article useful  (it also describes read & write alias): https://medium.com/craftsmenltd/rebuild-elasticsearch-index-without-downtime-168363829ea4